# PNG in Firemonkey : how to specify Compression and 8-bit

Tags: delphi, png, firemonkey

VCL allows me to specify a PNG's Compression level (not referring to Quality level).

How do I specify the Compression level of a PNG in FireMonkey?  Is there a way to save the PNG as 8-bit instead of 32-bit?

I'm using `TBitmapCodecManager`.  I only need 8-bit because the colors are only black/white (with some anti-aliasing).

Note: I cannot use an external PNG library as this has to be integrated in my code.

```
begin
  var oStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  var Surface := TBitmapSurface.Create;
  try
    BitmapCodecSaveParams.Quality := 100;  // PNG is 100% loss-less, how can we specify the Compression level?
    Surface.Assign(aBitmap);
    TBitmapCodecManager.SaveToStream(oStream, Surface, '.png', @BitmapCodecSaveParams);
  finally
    oMemoryStream.Free;
    Surf.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The correct terms to look for would be [color depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth) or at least [channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_(digital_image)). For PNG you'd either want [a palette or grayscale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Pixel_format) in general. Also PNG cannot have a quality level, as it will always save without loss - that one choice is just for how fast/effective the picture is compressed.

Comment: @AmigoJack  how do I specify a compression level for PNG just like in VCL?  How do I specify color depth (i'm ok with using grayscale or minimal color depth).

Comment: Show a [minimal, complete, verifiable and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
 With such example, we will be able to understand what you use, how far you have been in coding and it will be a good start to help you.

Comment: @fpiette updated with a minimal example - this is commonly used code to save png